# How to get anon aysnc function lineItems out of stripe.checkout.session.listLineItems request into a lambda return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, stripe-payments

I have the following code, that I want to take the lineItems return in the async function inside stripe.checkout... to return in the body of the lambda try section. I have tried running a .then on the test and many other configuritations and can't quite figure it out. I only can console log the lineItems inside the async function which is good, but I need to return it in the body, below the statusCode.

Hopefully someone can help

```
require("dotenv").config()
const stripe = require("stripe")(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_API_SECRET}`)
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    var eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body)

    console.log(eventBody.customer_id)

    var test = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
      eventBody.customer_id,
      { limit: 5 },
      async function (err, lineItems) {
        return lineItems
      }
    )

   //TRIED TEST.THEN((OK)=>...

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: eventBody }),
      // ADD LINE ITEMS TO THE BODY 
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: err.toString() }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the `stripe` call in `Promise` and wait for resolve/reject.

Try this:

```js
require("dotenv").config()
const stripe = require("stripe")(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_API_SECRET}`)

const checkoutUser = (customerId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
      customerId,
      { limit: 5 },
      (err, lineItems) => {
        if(err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(lineItems)
      }
    )
  })
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body)

    console.log(eventBody.customer_id)

    const lineItems = await checkoutUser(eventBody.customer_id);

    // use lineItems here
    
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: eventBody }),
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: err.toString() }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it best to separate the checkoutUser ousitde the exports.handler like you have here. And it worked great just gonna wait for it to let me accept the anwser.

Comment: @AndersKitson If this helped you then could you please mark it as an answer so that it would be easier for others who are facing the same problem to find a solution among all the answers that may be here.

Comment: yep it just had a 5 minute rule to accept. But thanks, for the help!

Comment: I think there should be ```reject(err)``` instead of ```reject(e)```

Comment: @Timofey Pchelintsev, good catch. Thanks)